# How to set a color for a specific row in pandastable, using python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a simple pandastable form in python, but I have some problems getting the rows in colors.

I have tried the following definition from the documentation, but it does not seem to work?

```
pt.setRowColors(rows=rows1, clr="red")
```

Here is my code:

```
# pandas as pt
# rows1 is a list of rows i would like to color       

app = tk.Tk()
f = tk.Frame(app)
f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
pt = Table(f, dataframe=myData, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
pt.show()
pt.setRowColors(rows=rows1, clr="red")
pt.redraw()
```

I wanted 30 rows to have a red background, but it does nothing. I do not even get an error to go by...

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pandastable API docs](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandastable.html#pandastable.core.Table.setRowColors) suggest you should use a Hex value for the colour:

> setRowColors(rows=None, clr=None, cols=None)[source]
>   Set rows color from menu. :param rows: row numbers to be colored :param clr: color in hex :param cols: column numbers, can also use ‘all’

So, according to this, the following should color all rows red in row1:

```
setRowColors(rows=rows1, clr='#FF0000', cols=None)
```